# Display the name of the outdoor instructor who has the most duties as an activity supervisor

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

The Schema is:
 ACTIVITY_SUPERVISOR (SupervisorID)
 OUTDOOR_INSTRUCTOR (InstructorID, InstrName, InstrPhone, SupervisorID)

This is what I wrote but its not working

```
 SELECT O.InstructorID, O.InstrName, O.SupervisorID, A.SupervisorID, COUNT(*) 
 FROM Outdoor_instructor O, Activity_supervisor A 
 INNER JOIN Activity_supervisor A ON A.SupervisorID = O.SupervisorID 
 GROUP BY SupervisorID O, InstrName O 
 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC 
 LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: what is not working? LIMIT 1? i don't think that PL/SQL?

Comment: theres an error on line 4, it is sql oracle

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: SQL>  SELECT O.InstructorID, O.InstrName, O.SupervisorID, A.SupervisorID, COUNT(*)
  2   FROM Outdoor_instructor O, Activity_supervisor A
  3   INNER JOIN Activity_supervisor A ON A.SupervisorID = O.SupervisorID
  4   GROUP BY SupervisorID O, InstrName O
  5   ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
  6   LIMIT 1;
 GROUP BY SupervisorID O, InstrName O
                       *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two references to "Activity_supervisor A" in your query. 
There should also be more values in your group by segment

Try this:

```
 SELECT O.InstructorID, O.InstrName, O.SupervisorID, A.SupervisorID, COUNT(*) 
 FROM Outdoor_instructor O
 INNER JOIN Activity_supervisor A ON A.SupervisorID = O.SupervisorID 
 WHERE rownum = 1
 GROUP BY O.InstructorID, O.InstrName, O.SupervisorID, A.SupervisorID 
 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: this should work for you. as i mentioned there is no "Limit" keyword for PL/SQL, "Limit" is for MYSQL.

Comment: SQL> SELECT O.InstructorID, O.InstrName, O.SupervisorID, A.SupervisorID, COUNT(*)
  2   FROM Outdoor_instructor O
  3   INNER JOIN Activity_supervisor A ON A.SupervisorID = O.SupervisorID
  4   GROUP BY O.InstructorID, O.InstrName, O.SupervisorID, A.SupervisorID
  5   WHERE rownum = 1
  6   ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
  7  ;
 WHERE rownum = 1
 *
ERROR at line 5:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: Updated my answer. Placed the where clause in wrong order. Please try again @TuğçeDemir

Comment: I think I got it Thanks

Comment: Great! Please upvote if my answered helped :) @TuğçeDemir